# retrieve HashMap list into another list , one key having many values

Tags: java, hashmap

I am saving values into an `Hashmap<String,Records>`
Sample value `1,objRecord1`,`2,objRecord2`,`1,objRecord3` so on... I need to retrieve values of all records from hashmap whose string is 1

something like
(I am messing here itself)
`arrayList myArraylist=Hashmap.get(1);`

Comment: `HashMap` cannot have two elements with the same key.

Comment: Then what should I use ?

Comment: You can use a `MultiMap` implementation from apache commons (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) or google collections

Comment: Map<String,List<Records>> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrayList myArraylist=Hashmap.get("1");
```

To satisfy that  your Hashmap declaration must be

```
Map<String,List<Record>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

While adding add to `list`

**Example for Adding in to `map`:**

```
  if(myMap.containsKey("1")){
         myMap.put("1", myMap.get("1").add(new Record()));//record obj
      }else{
         List<Record> list = new ArrayList<>();
         list.add(record);
         myMap.put("1", list));
     }
```

**Getting back**

```
 List<Record> list = myMap.get("1");
```

Comment: how do I add & retrieve the values?

Comment: @onkar Updated my post. Hope that helps. Let me know for further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `Multimap` would be easiest, in my opinion.

http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

That is if you're willing to add a dependency on google commons :)

NOTE: this is not the same as `MultiMap` (notice the case difference) from apache commons.

Comment: I'd also recommend the Guava library over the apache commons one.  One import that solves many problems.

Comment: Yes. Guava makes use of Generics. Apache Commons doesn't

Comment: Agreed -- Guava is a great library

Answer (score 0):

Use List or Set as Values, Then keep update that list or Set.

```
 Hashmap<String, ArrayList<Records>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your multiple records per key need to be ordered ? If so, something like:

```
Map<String, List<Record>>
```

is suitable. Otherwise a Guava MultiMap would be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Better will be to use List as values in hashmap.

Something like: `HashMap<String, List<Record>>`

When you want to put record in map, you can do something like:

```
void insertRecord(String key, Record record){
    List<Record> records = map.get(key);
    if(records == null){
        records = new ArrayList<Record>();
        map.put(key, records);
    }
    records.add(record);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want mulitple records per key then better to use Set of records for the values

```
Map<String, Set<Record>>
```